ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image gitlab-runner-helper
I have a two-stage CI flow which will build code automatically and run the unit test.
The first stage works well but I got an error in stage two.
Any hint for this?
Suppose the container remains exist in the second stage, and it can access cloned branch and built files there.
gitlab-ci.yml:
stages:
- build
- test

build-code:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - echo "Current working directory:"
    - pwd
    - cd cpp
    - mkdir -p build
    - cd build
    - cmake ..
    - make -j12
  cache:
    paths:
      - cpp/build

run-unittest:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - git clone https://github.com/google/googletest/
    - cd googletest
    - mkdir build
    - cd build
    - cmake ..
    - make -j12
    - sudo make install 
    - ls 

docker-compose:
version: '3'

services:
  gitlab-runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
    container_name: gitlab-runner 
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml:/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml



According to this post:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/28973

Just add this line manually in the config.toml
helper_image = "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-bd40e3da"

